# Trying to understand UART packets I'm sending/receiving over a TCP connection

Tags: c, tcp, command, packet, uart

I'm working on a project that a previous engineer started. Basically, we're sending data from a microcontroller to our server using a WiFi module.

Here is how I've interpreted the code so far:

-The module creates an AP, which the user connects to.
-The user then enters an IP/URL, which allows them to select their WiFi network.
-The module now communicates over the selected network.
-The module connects a socket to our TCP server every second and sends a packet.
-If the server has a command for the client, it responds with a command packet.

My confusion here is trying to understand the packet structures.

The packets the client sends out start with [ESC][Z]['Connection ID'][0][0][0][6]. I'm assuming this has something to do with a predefined UART layout, but I have never used UART before.

The server then responds, if there is a command, with a packet that also starts with [ESC][Z]['Connection ID'][0][0][0][6]. However, the client then responds with a packet that starts [ESC][Z]['Connection ID'] followed by the data.

So what is the '0006' heading my packets, and why aren't these values needed in the client responses? I'm assuming that the 'ESC' is necessary to send data outside of the network, and that the 'Z' is a predefined header. However, please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Could it be a byte length? I.e. no. of data bytes following. The Client response to the command just looks like an acknowledgement.

Comment: I really don't know why I didn't think of that immediately, yea the code that follows is the serial # which comes to 6 bytes. The documentation for the WiFi module listed some of the UART commands but didn't explain the data which is why I was so thrown off. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the header are just the number of bytes left in the packet after the header bytes. ><

Comment: Hey! That's my answer ;-)